# Tensor Flow Import Error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

Kindly help with this error: [image]

While importing tensorflow , i am facing above error as

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Comment: Looks like there are several other issues. How have you installed `tensorflow`

Comment: Please post the error and the code that caused it as text instead of a screenshot, this is more likely to attract people to answer your question.

Comment: Just a side note, please don't post images of the text/code. Better to format it in the post itself or provide a link to the Pastebin site.

Comment: @BrianH. : Sure thanks

Comment: @FlyingTeller : Yes i have installed tensorflow

Comment: @Mohan The answer to "How have you installed tensorflow" is not "Yes I have installed tensorflow"

Comment: @FlyingTeller: Sorry my bad....I downloaded the tensorflow files from anaconda and then through conda prompt installed it by running conda install -c filepath. Post installation i checked the status as installed in anaconda environment - root.

Comment: Does importing tensorflow work outside of Jupyter? Like when you run `python -c "import tensorflow"` in your terminal?